# wlan1 showing up as weird characters

Tags: character-encoding, wifi

When I type ifconfig, this should show as "wlan1", but it's showing as

```
wlanx00c0c8476b6:
```

What in the world is this encoding? How can I check the encoding and reset it if need be? Surely this can't be right!

Comment: Please do not use text images (especially sideways and taken-from-a-camera images). EVER. This seems to be off topic as well as it is about networking and the command line, not programming.

Comment: I took the picture upright. I didnt mean for it to do that. Then where do I go for this problem?

Comment: There. No more picture.

Comment: http://superuser.com/